# Placing window in full screen mode to a half of the screen

Tags: unity, compiz

Is there a way to keep an application in full screen mode after placing it to a half of the screen? The question is about Ubuntu Unity, but other DE are relevant too.

On Ubuntu [16.04, Unity, Compiz] it is possible to toggle full screen mode (via F11, for example) and move the window to a part of the screen (via ctrl + Super + left_arrow, for example): [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYUX7.png). But if I move focus to another window and then move it back to the full-screened one, it simultaneously exposes to the whole screen. So is there a way to do not let it to expose? I've looked up for it in CompizConfig, but found nothing.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution for this. 
My most important use case was video streams - this I solved in chrome by using this extensions: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-screen-for-google-ch/gmimocjjppdelmhpcmpkhekmpoddgima . With this extension, if you "full screen" a video, you are asked if this shall be a "windowed fullscreen", a "PIP-Like fullscreen" (only video without borders but of arbitrary size) or a "real fullscreen".